# Append csv files in multiple folders into one dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have csv files, called "`toyexample`" in multiple subfolders. I want to append all csv files called `toyexample` in all the subfolders.
The path folders are as follows:

```
C:/Users/xxx/Dropbox/College/Project1/2005Q1/
C:/Users/xxx/Dropbox/College/Project1/2005Q2/
.....
.....
C:/Users/xxx/Dropbox/College/Project1/2015Q3/
C:/Users/xxx/Dropbox/College/Project1/2015Q4/
```

Hence, the path subfolders range from 2005Q1 to 2015Q4.
Each of these subfolders has many csv files, but I only want to extract the one named `toyexample`.

I am trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = ["subfolder1", "folder2", ....."subfolder44"]
appended_file = []
subpaths = os.listdir(path)

for pa in subpaths:
    df = pd.read_csv("toyexample")
    appended_file.append(df)
```

I was wondering how to automate the process of reading the files from so many different directories instead of inputting them manually myself. I also need help with reading the files (perhaps with `os.path_join()`) and appending them into one dataframe `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `glob` with `recursive=True` to find the paths of all files named `toyexample.csv` in your file tree.

```
glob.glob("**/toyexample.csv", recursive=True)
```

Will give you a list of paths starting in your current working directory for each `toyexample.csv` which you can then process.

Answer (score 0):

with help from user ChuHo, I was able to work out the following:

```
import glob
import os 
import pandas as pd

paths = glob.glob("CC:/Users/xxx/Dropbox/College/Project1/**/toyexample.csv", recursive=True)

appended_file = []
for i in paths:
    df = pd.read_csv(i)
    appended_file.append(df)
    combined=pd.concat(appended_file, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```